# Local class definitions: why does this work

Tags: java, android

Why does the following style of code work:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do something based on the intent's action
    }
}
```

I would expect it to be:

```
private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver () {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do something based on the intent's action
    }
}

MyBroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
```

In the 1st code piece above, how does the compiler know that `receiver` is of type `MyBroadcastReceiver` and not `BroadcastReceiver`? Isn't this ambiguous? Why is this allowed?

If I define:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver2 = new BroadcastReceiver();
```

Now is `receiver == reciver2`?

**EDIT:**
BroadcastReceiver 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Is `BroadcastReceiver` an interface?

Comment: No. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an *anonymous class declaration*. See [section 15.9.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9.5) of the JLS for more details:

> An anonymous class declaration is automatically derived from a class instance creation expression by the compiler.

The type of the `receiver` variable actually *is* just `BroadcastReceiver` - but the type of the object created is an instance of `ContainingClass$1` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 4):

It works because you are using an [anonymous class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes#Anonymous_Classes)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating here an unnamed class, which extends BroadcastReciever. This is usual in Java e.g. to create Listeners. As the unnamed class extends BroadcastReciever it can be used by a reference of that type.

Answer (score 1):

This is called an *anonymous inner class*. As this name indicates, such a class has no name.

It will be compiled to a .class file name `EnclosingClass$1.class`. The class file of the receiver2 variable will be `EnclosingClass$2.class`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the class `receiver` is NOT an instance of MyBroadcastReceiver; it is an anonymous instance of BroadcastReceiver.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}

MyBroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

(receiver instanceof MyBroadcastReceiver); // is FALSE
(receiver instanceof BroadcastReceiver); // is TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the 1st code piece above, how does the compiler know that receiver is of type `MyBroadcastReceiver` and not `BroadcastReceiver`?

It does not, you simply created an instance of an [*anonymous class*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes#Anonymous_Classes) extending `BroadcastReceiver` with a specific implementation.

> Now is `receiver == reciver2`?

Clearly no: they are two distinct instances (even though they both *extend* `BroadcastReceiver`).